# Use of Take() LINQ Method in Entity Framework Core v3.1.4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a limit GET query parameter in my API request (i.e. ?limit=10) and the value of this limit will then be used by the `Take()` LINQ method to get only the number of results I want. What I want to do is to include the LINQ `Take()` method as part of the LINQ-TO-T-SQL query and perform the limit as part of the SQL query. I tried the following codes below. I also captured the error stack trace.

Code 1: For this code, I'm trying to use the `Take()` on my top level resource in the query. Then afterwards (in the declaration of `q`), I'm performing sub-queries related to the top level resource.

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Take(2);

var q = from doctor in baseQuery

        let sp = (from ds in db.DoctorSpecialty
                  join s in db.Specialty on ds.SpecialtyID equals s.SpecialtyID
                  where ds.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                  select new
                  {
                      s.SpecialtyID,
                      s.Specialty1
                  }).ToList()

        let clinics = (from c in db.Clinic
                  where c.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID && c.Active == true

                  let schedule = (from sc in db.Schedule
                                  where sc.ClinicID == c.ClinicID
                                    && sc.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                                    && DoctorDirectoryConstants.ValidScheduleNotes.Contains(sc.Notes)
                                  select sc).ToList()

                  select new
                  {
                      c.ClinicID,
                      c.Street,
                      c.ClinicName,
                      c.ContactNumber,
                      c.City,
                      c.Province,
                      c.HomeNumber,
                      c.MobileNumber,
                      c.WorkNumber,
                      c.Email,
                      Schedules = schedule,
                  }).ToList() 
        select new
        {
            Doctor = doctor,
            Specialties = sp,
            Clinics = clinics

        };

var rs = q.ToList();
```

Error stack trace for code 1:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[DoctorID], [t].[Address], [t].[AvailableInvites], [t].[Birthdate], [t].[City], [t].[CityID], [t].[ContactNumber], [t].[Country], [t].[DateRegistered], [t].[Description], [t].[DoctorUrl], [t].[Email], [t].[EmailActivated], [t].[EmailUID], [t].[EmailVerifiedFirstTime], [t].[Facebook], [t].[FirstName], [t].[Gender], [t].[GooglePlus], [t].[HomeNumber], [t].[Image], [t].[LastName], [t].[LinkedIn], [t].[MainSpecialty], [t].[ManuallyVerified], [t].[MedicalSchool], [t].[MedicalSchoolYear], [t].[MiddleName], [t].[MobileNumber], [t].[Nationality], [t].[OriginalIssueDate], [t].[PRCNumber], [t].[PageOkay], [t].[PatientNumber], [t].[PhicNumber], [t].[PractisingSince], [t].[Province], [t].[PtrNumber], [t].[Residency], [t].[ResidencyYear], [t].[S2Number], [t].[ShowPublicProfile], [t].[Status], [t].[Street], [t].[Suffix], [t].[Title], [t].[Twitter], [t].[UserID], [t].[Website], [t].[WorkNumber], [t].[Zipcode], [t0].[SpecialtyID], [t0].[Specialty], [t0].[Id], [t2].[ClinicID], [t2].[Street], [t2].[ClinicName], [t2].[ContactNumber], [t2].[City], [t2].[Province], [t2].[HomeNumber], [t2].[MobileNumber], [t2].[WorkNumber], [t2].[Email], [t2].[ScheduleID], [t2].[Active], [t2].[ClinicID0], [t2].[DateModified], [t2].[DayOfWeek], [t2].[DoctorID], [t2].[Notes], [t2].[StartFrom], [t2].[TimeEnd], [t2].[TimeStart], [t2].[Until]
      FROM (
          SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [d].[DoctorID], [d].[Address], [d].[AvailableInvites], [d].[Birthdate], [d].[City], [d].[CityID], [d].[ContactNumber], [d].[Country], [d].[DateRegistered], [d].[Description], [d].[DoctorUrl], [d].[Email], [d].[EmailActivated], [d].[EmailUID], [d].[EmailVerifiedFirstTime], [d].[Facebook], [d].[FirstName], [d].[Gender], [d].[GooglePlus], [d].[HomeNumber], [d].[Image], [d].[LastName], [d].[LinkedIn], [d].[MainSpecialty], [d].[ManuallyVerified], [d].[MedicalSchool], [d].[MedicalSchoolYear], [d].[MiddleName], [d].[MobileNumber], [d].[Nationality], [d].[OriginalIssueDate], [d].[PRCNumber], [d].[PageOkay], [d].[PatientNumber], [d].[PhicNumber], [d].[PractisingSince], [d].[Province], [d].[PtrNumber], [d].[Residency], [d].[ResidencyYear], [d].[S2Number], [d].[ShowPublicProfile], [d].[Status], [d].[Street], [d].[Suffix], [d].[Title], [d].[Twitter], [d].[UserID], [d].[Website], [d].[WorkNumber], [d].[Zipcode]
          FROM [Doctor] AS [d]
          WHERE [d].[Status] = 'good'
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [s].[SpecialtyID], [s].[Specialty], [d0].[Id], [d0].[DoctorID]
          FROM [DoctorSpecialty] AS [d0]
          INNER JOIN [Specialty] AS [s] ON [d0].[SpecialtyID] = [s].[SpecialtyID]
      ) AS [t0] ON [t].[DoctorID] = [t0].[DoctorID]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [c].[ClinicID], [c].[Street], [c].[ClinicName], [c].[ContactNumber], [c].[City], [c].[Province], [c].[HomeNumber], [c].[MobileNumber], [c].[WorkNumber], [c].[Email], [t1].[ScheduleID], [t1].[Active], [t1].[ClinicID] AS [ClinicID0], [t1].[DateModified], [t1].[DayOfWeek], [t1].[DoctorID], [t1].[Notes], [t1].[StartFrom], [t1].[TimeEnd], [t1].[TimeStart], [t1].[Until], [c].[DoctorID] AS [DoctorID0]
          FROM [Clinic] AS [c]
          LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT [s0].[ScheduleID], [s0].[Active], [s0].[ClinicID], [s0].[DateModified], [s0].[DayOfWeek], [s0].[DoctorID], [s0].[Notes], [s0].[StartFrom], [s0].[TimeEnd], [s0].[TimeStart], [s0].[Until]
              FROM [Schedule] AS [s0]
              WHERE ([s0].[DoctorID] = [d].[DoctorID]) AND [s0].[Notes] IN (N'Walk-In', N'By Appointment')
          ) AS [t1] ON [c].[ClinicID] = [t1].[ClinicID]
          WHERE [c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)
      ) AS [t2] ON [t].[DoctorID] = [t2].[DoctorID0]
      ORDER BY [t].[DoctorID], [t0].[Id], [t0].[SpecialtyID], [t2].[ClinicID], [t2].[ScheduleID]
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'SeriousMDCommonsCore.Models.Database.SeriousmdEntitiesContext'.
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The multi-part identifier "d.DoctorID" could not be bound.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
      ClientConnectionId:0b10b611-bd0f-4fcb-a543-fdbe530fc029
      Error Number:4104,State:1,Class:16
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The multi-part identifier "d.DoctorID" could not be bound.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:0b10b611-bd0f-4fcb-a543-fdbe530fc029
Error Number:4104,State:1,Class:16
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM03JVLBFS8O", Request id "0HM03JVLBFS8O:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The multi-part identifier "d.DoctorID" could not be bound.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
ClientConnectionId:0b10b611-bd0f-4fcb-a543-fdbe530fc029
Error Number:4104,State:1,Class:16
```

Code 2: Here, instead of performing the `Take()` in the `baseQuery`, I'm performing the `Take()` in the final query expression `q`. I also added a `doctor.DoctorID` as some sort of `id` that I think is required to be fed to the `Take()` LINQ method

```
var q = from doctor in baseQuery

        let sp = (from ds in db.DoctorSpecialty
                  join s in db.Specialty on ds.SpecialtyID equals s.SpecialtyID
                  where ds.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                  select new
                  {
                      s.SpecialtyID,
                      s.Specialty1
                  }).ToList()

        let clinics = (from c in db.Clinic
                  where c.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID && c.Active == true

                  let schedule = (from sc in db.Schedule
                                  where sc.ClinicID == c.ClinicID
                                    && sc.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                                    && DoctorDirectoryConstants.ValidScheduleNotes.Contains(sc.Notes)
                                  select sc).ToList()

                  select new
                  {
                      c.ClinicID,
                      c.Street,
                      c.ClinicName,
                      c.ContactNumber,
                      c.City,
                      c.Province,
                      c.HomeNumber,
                      c.MobileNumber,
                      c.WorkNumber,
                      c.Email,
                      Schedules = schedule,
                  }).ToList() 
        select new
        {
            doctor.DoctorID,
            Doctor = doctor,
            Specialties = sp,
            Clinics = clinics

        };

q = q.Take(2);

var rs = q.ToList();
```

Error stack trace for code 2: Here, the error changed from that of code 2 and it seems that the added index is being used by the `Take()` LINQ method but still throws an error.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM03K296O68T", Request id "0HM03K296O68T:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression '(ProjectionBindingExpression: 0)' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Back to my question, how can I integrate the `Take()` LINQ method as part of my LINQ-TO-T-SQL query so that all of my queries will go through EF Core and all query operations will be performed in database?

Comment: Which version of EF core are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm using EF Core v3.1.4

Comment: usually when you have lets, and `ToList()` these are like cte's/temp tables in sql, so separate it out so its easier to understand, aka what i would do is just write the sql which i want it to generate and then convert that to linq. It easier when what you want to do, is not straight forward, as you better understand the limits of the tools. What ever you can do in sql you can make in linq. so make the query in sql and then it will help how to make it in linq.

Comment: I mean as soon as you `ToList()` on any part you are executing it. but some times that has to be done... like a CTE/Temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query try changing `doctor.DoctorID` in:

```
let schedule = (from sc in db.Schedule
                where sc.ClinicID == c.ClinicID
                && sc.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                && DoctorDirectoryConstants.ValidScheduleNotes.Contains(sc.Notes)
                select sc)
```

to `c.DoctorID`:

```
let schedule = (from sc in db.Schedule
                where sc.ClinicID == c.ClinicID
                && sc.DoctorID == c.DoctorID
                && DoctorDirectoryConstants.ValidScheduleNotes.Contains(sc.Notes)
                select sc)
```

**UPD**

If you go through the SQL you will see the code generated for schedules:

```
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT [s0].[ScheduleID], [s0].[Active], [s0].[ClinicID], [s0].[DateModified], [s0].[DayOfWeek], [s0].[DoctorID], [s0].[Notes], [s0].[StartFrom], [s0].[TimeEnd], [s0].[TimeStart], [s0].[Until]
              FROM [Schedule] AS [s0]
              WHERE ([s0].[DoctorID] = [d].[DoctorID]) AND [s0].[Notes] IN (N'Walk-In', N'By Appointment')
          ) AS [t1] ON [c].[ClinicID] = [t1].[ClinicID]
```

Check out the where clause it has `WHERE ([s0].[DoctorID] = [d].[DoctorID])` condition which references `[d].[DoctorID]` which is not accessible cause it is accessible only in the root subselect which performs `Take`. It seems that there is a convoluted bug in EF Core.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, it works now for Code 1. Thanks a lot!. Can you please explain the reason for it to be working?

Answer (score 0):

Code 3: This version of my code successfully returns the number of results I wanted via the `Take()` LINQ method. However, the `Take()` is being performed on data / collection that is already loaded in the client side or in memory. So this `Take()` performs a LINQ-TO-Collections query instead of LINQ-TO-T-SQL and doesn't go through EF Core.

```
var q = from doctor in baseQuery

        let sp = (from ds in db.DoctorSpecialty
                  join s in db.Specialty on ds.SpecialtyID equals s.SpecialtyID
                  where ds.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                  select new
                  {
                      s.SpecialtyID,
                      s.Specialty1
                  }).ToList()

        let clinics = (from c in db.Clinic
                  where c.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID && c.Active == true

                  let schedule = (from sc in db.Schedule
                                  where sc.ClinicID == c.ClinicID
                                    && sc.DoctorID == doctor.DoctorID
                                    && DoctorDirectoryConstants.ValidScheduleNotes.Contains(sc.Notes)
                                  select sc).ToList()

                  select new
                  {
                      c.ClinicID,
                      c.Street,
                      c.ClinicName,
                      c.ContactNumber,
                      c.City,
                      c.Province,
                      c.HomeNumber,
                      c.MobileNumber,
                      c.WorkNumber,
                      c.Email,
                      Schedules = schedule,
                  }).ToList() 
        select new
        {
            Doctor = doctor,
            Specialties = sp,
            Clinics = clinics

        };

var rs = q.ToList();

rs = rs.AsEnumerable().Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: just FYI you don't need `AsEnumerable()` in `rs = rs.AsEnumerable().Take(2).ToList()`

Comment: Hi @GuruStron noted. Thanks! I tried it and it works
`rs = rs.Take(2).ToList();`